# Search engine for graphs where we can specify the axis we are looking for

Tags: tool-request, search-engine

Are there some search engines where I could search for graphs by specifying the axis I am looking for? E.g. axis 1: year; axis 2: price to store 1 TB on a hard drive.

Comment: I think you're best off looking for the raw data and then graphing it yourself. The closest I think you'll get is WolframAlpha. For example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=population+of+texas+over+time

Answer (score 3):

Although not strictly open data, the in my experience most fruitful way to search for something like this is:

- Search for the raw data (timeseries, tables, values) in studies/statistics oneself and prepare the graph oneself or
- do a simple Google image search like [graph hdd storage price](https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=graph%20hdd%20storage%20price&tbs=imgo:1).